# iOS XMPP how to call -xmppStreamDidAuthenticate

Tags: ios, xmpp

I am working on XMPP based project. I want to know that how to call 
`- (void)xmppStreamDidAuthenticate:(XMPPStream *)sender`

method on login button.?
**Note:** i want to call this method on login button. so , login will sucessful and move to home view controller. (i dont want to write code for move to next view controller in appdelegate.h)